Troubleshooting hall effect sensor circuit
For context I have an engine that's reporting camshaft position correlation with crankshaft position faults. When looking at position data with diagnostic tools the camshaft position remains static when the engine is running.
To troubleshoot why the camshaft position sensor (hall effect sensor) is not receiving any values I've disassembled the wiring for the faulty sensor as well as the wiring for an adjacent camshaft position sensor that seems to be working correctly.
Both sensors share a common 5v wire as well as a common ground wire, they have separate signal wires that go back to the ECU.
When testing the wires unplugged all seem to be working correctly: 5v wires read 5v, ground wires show continuity to the body of the vehicle, signal wires read 4.6v.
The difference appears when connected to the hall effect sensors: on the faulty sensor when the ground wire is connected, the signal wire drops down to 1.2v and moving metal objects near the sensor has no effect, if ground wire is removed for the sensor the signal wire goes back to 4.6v. On the good sensor the signal wire reads 4.6v when theres no metal objects near the sensor and to 200mv when there's a metal object near the sensor. I also noticed that I could measure 5v between the 5v pin and the signal pin, if the ground pin is disconnected this reading goes to 0v as if the signal pin was being grounded despite the pins being isolated from each other.
What's concerning is that the same result is observed when the sensors are swapped which leads me to think that it's not an issue with the sensors themselves but rather the signal wires.
What could be the cause of a signal wire coming from the ECU to behave like this when connected to a hall effect sensor?
The issue seems to explain why the camshaft position remains static but I can't come up with a reason for this to happen considering that swapping sensors makes no difference, could this be a sign of a bad ECU?

check that both the +5 and ground wires actually connect to the sensor. -  eg: the plug or socket may be damaged

thanks for the suggestion @Jasen but both the ground and +5 seem securely attached to the sensor, if I keep my positive probe on the signal wire (and negative on the body of the vehicle) the reading goes up to 4.6 as soon as I disconnect the ground wire from the sensor.

What's the error code? Static measurements may not help. What happens when testing both camshaft sensors by waving a screwdriver blade past them and observing their signals on a multimeter (if possible) or oscilloscope for analog/digital signal? Engine heat can affect sensor operation. Guess how I know?

Error code is P0017, intake camshaft sensor (good one) behaves normally: reads 4.6v with no metal object near and around 0.2v with metal object next to sensor, the exhaust cam sensor (the bad one) shows 1.2v as soon as the ground is connected to the sensor. It's almost as if the signal wire is partially leaking to the ground wire but not fully. Tested with the same sensor, intake cam sensor plug behaves normally while  the exhaust cam plug does not.

check the wires for concealed breaks in the conductor.
